# Can't delete Matlab directory in MacOS because "directory not empty"

Tags: macos, matlab, terminal, delete-file, rm

I have uninstalled Matlab with a software for deleting applications (AppCleaner), but I can't delete a directory in the Trash.
The directory is "MATLAB_R2018b.app".

If I click on "empty trash" I get the error "The operation can’t be completed because the item “MATLAB_R2018b” is in use", even if it isn't in use and I checked that with the Activity Monitor.

Also I tried manually using the terminal. I tried with `rm -rf MATLAB_R2018b.app` and `suto rm -rf MATLAB_R2018b.app`, but I got the error `rm: MATLAB_R2018b.app/toolbox/matlab/datatools/variableeditor/js/peer/release/dgrid/css: Directory not empty`.
The problem is that if I go that directory it is empty! Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm that is odd. The error seems to indicate that the `toolbox` directory still exists inside of `MATLAB_R2018b.app`

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: @Suever yes, I can go inside `MATLAB_R2018b.app` directory.
@CrisLuengo yes.

Comment: Try to rename the directory by using the bash command mv originalName newName and then delete the directory

Comment: @MichaelC. same problem with newName...

Comment: Are there any hidden files that start with a dot? You could navigate to your directory with the terminal and type "ls -all". If you see only two entries (one with a single and one with double dot) then the directory is truly empty

Comment: yes, I tried and the directory is empty...

Comment: You might want to try using the MacOS recovery mode to start a shell and retry what you have tried so far. To do so, press command and R at the same time after you start your machine. In the menu bar, you can open a terminal, navigate to your folder and give all your previous attempts another shot. Good luck

Comment: I have the same problem also in recovery mode...